# Why can't I use ~0 to initialize signed char?

Tags: c, ansi-c

I wrote like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

main()
{
    signed char i = ~0;
    printf("%zu\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

But the result is `4294967295` instead of `-1`. Why does this happen?

Comment: `%zu` is for `size_t`, not for `signed char`.

Comment: The `u` ins `%zu` means **unsigned**, and `-1` is not a possible interpretation of an `unsigned` value.

Comment: "Why can't I use..." You can. The initialization is fine.

Comment: When I asked this question, I doubted whether I initialized wrongly and I didn't make sure the usage of %zu, so I asked like this. I'm not complaining barbecue or burger, I'm asking why. One more question: When you know the answer, will you ask others for help? @P__J__

Comment: @SearonMeng No because I would start from the *`man`printf`* and learn something about the formats. But its me. You are free to post the question first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `signed char` value in an expression, it is automatically converted to `int`. Then, when you print a signed `int` using a format specifier `%zu`, which is for formatting an unsigned `size_t`, you get erroneous results because of the mismatch.

To print a `signed char` correctly, using `%hhd`.

Additionally, you should understand that while a `signed char` value of −1 might be represented with the eight bits 11111111 (in eight-bit two’s complement), when it is converted to `int`, the result is the 32 bits 11111111111111111111111111111111 (which represents −1 using 32-bit two’s complement). When those bits are interpreted as a 32-bit unsigned integer, the result is 4294967295. That explains why “4294967295” may be printed rather than the “255” that would result from interpreting the eight-bit 11111111 as an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing i value using %zu. In unisgned format -1=2^32-1 which is equals to
4294967295. Compiler uses the formula 2^(sizeoftype in bits)-n to convert signed values to unsigned.